# WiX unable to copy to C drive on only one computer

Tags: wix

I have built a WiX installer for an application and in it I need to copy some files to a specific folder on the "C:" drive.  I originally coded my directories like this:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="MyCompanyInstall" Name="MyCompany">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYROOT" Name="MyCompany" FileSource="[WindowsVolume]\MyCompany">
      <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYMYSPECIALFOLDERDATAFOLDER" Name="MySpecialFolder">
        <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYMYSPECIALFOLDERTRENDINGFOLDER" Name="Trending"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="MyCompanyProgramMenu" Name="MyCompany">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="$(var.ProductName)"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYCOMPANYROOT">
    <Component Id="CreateDirectories" Guid="60D9E460-89C8-42D2-8581-D858785A1817">
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYROOT"/>
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTDATAFOLDER"/>
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTTRENDINGFOLDER"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <!-- trimmed -->
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTDATAFOLDER">
    <Component Id="FirstFile.xml" Guid="E9879B51-1C74-47BF-A475-3B77D66297E2">
      <File Id="FirstFile.xml" Source="$(var.TargetDir)FirstFile.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="SecondFile.xml" Guid="69A86F79-4596-4714-9FE7-628882ADA303">
      <File Id="SecondFile.xml" Source="$(var.TargetDir)SecondFile.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="MyCompanyMyProductHelp.pdf" Guid="D2D3CDF1-61FA-4021-8F56-F23770580AA0">
      <File Id="MyCompanyMyProductHelp.pdf" Source="$(var.TargetDir)Documents\MyCompany My Product Help.pdf" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <!-- trimmed -->
  <Icon Id="$(var.ProductName)Icon.EXE" SourceFile="$(var.TargetPath)"/>
</Fragment>
```

But on one computer in the office I kept getting the case that the files meant for "C:\MyCompany\MySpecialFolder\" were not copied.  I then tried to hard code the "C:" drive like so:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="MyCompanyInstall" Name="MyCompany">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYROOT" Name="MyCompany" FileSource="C:\MyCompany">
      <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYMYSPECIALFOLDERDATAFOLDER" Name="MySpecialFolder">
        <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYMYSPECIALFOLDERTRENDINGFOLDER" Name="Trending"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="MyCompanyProgramMenu" Name="MyCompany">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="$(var.ProductName)"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYCOMPANYROOT">
    <Component Id="CreateDirectories" Guid="60D9E460-89C8-42D2-8581-D858785A1817">
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYROOT"/>
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTDATAFOLDER"/>
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTTRENDINGFOLDER"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <!-- trimmed -->
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTDATAFOLDER">
    <Component Id="FirstFile.xml" Guid="E9879B51-1C74-47BF-A475-3B77D66297E2">
      <File Id="FirstFile.xml" Source="$(var.TargetDir)FirstFile.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="SecondFile.xml" Guid="69A86F79-4596-4714-9FE7-628882ADA303">
      <File Id="SecondFile.xml" Source="$(var.TargetDir)SecondFile.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="MyCompanyMyProductHelp.pdf" Guid="D2D3CDF1-61FA-4021-8F56-F23770580AA0">
      <File Id="MyCompanyMyProductHelp.pdf" Source="$(var.TargetDir)Documents\MyCompany My Product Help.pdf" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <!-- trimmed -->
  <Icon Id="$(var.ProductName)Icon.EXE" SourceFile="$(var.TargetPath)"/>
</Fragment>
```

But I got the same results.

Does anyone know why this won't work on only one machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I stumbled upon a fix.  I don't understand why this fixes it, but it now works.

The key was to add the line:

```
  <SetDirectory Id="MYCOMPANYROOT" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyCompany"/>
```

I would have thought that the "FileSource" attribute in the "Directory" tag would have done the trick, but alas it didn't.

```
    <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYROOT" Name="MyCompany" FileSource="[WindowsVolume]MyCompany">
```

I don't really understand why I needed this.  If someone could explain, I would appreciate it.

Code follows:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="MyCompanyInstall" Name="MyCompany">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYROOT" Name="MyCompany" FileSource="[WindowsVolume]MyCompany">
      <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYMYSPECIALFOLDERDATAFOLDER" Name="MySpecialFolder">
        <Directory Id="MYCOMPANYMYSPECIALFOLDERTRENDINGFOLDER" Name="Trending"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="MyCompanyProgramMenu" Name="MyCompany">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="$(var.ProductName)"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
      <!-- New line -->
  <SetDirectory Id="MYCOMPANYROOT" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyCompany"/>
      <!--          -->
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYCOMPANYROOT">
    <Component Id="CreateDirectories" Guid="60D9E460-89C8-42D2-8581-D858785A1817">
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYROOT"/>
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTDATAFOLDER"/>
      <CreateFolder Directory="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTTRENDINGFOLDER"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <!-- trimmed -->
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYCOMPANYMYPRODUCTDATAFOLDER">
    <Component Id="FirstFile.xml" Guid="E9879B51-1C74-47BF-A475-3B77D66297E2">
      <File Id="FirstFile.xml" Source="$(var.TargetDir)FirstFile.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="SecondFile.xml" Guid="69A86F79-4596-4714-9FE7-628882ADA303">
      <File Id="SecondFile.xml" Source="$(var.TargetDir)SecondFile.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="MyCompanyMyProductHelp.pdf" Guid="D2D3CDF1-61FA-4021-8F56-F23770580AA0">
      <File Id="MyCompanyMyProductHelp.pdf" Source="$(var.TargetDir)Documents\MyCompany My Product Help.pdf" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <!-- trimmed -->
  <Icon Id="$(var.ProductName)Icon.EXE" SourceFile="$(var.TargetPath)"/>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: I think I understand your issue, I believe you are mixing up source and target.  The WIX file describes where you want to place the files (target), the source describes where you retrieve the files for packaging into the mdi (the payload).  I think you have confused the meaning of file source on your Directory element.  If you create a logfile using 'msiexec /i misname.msi /l*v log file.log' you will see the various values assigned to the SourceDir and TargetDir properties.

Comment: What SetDirectory is doing is overriding the value of MYCOMPANYROOT from what was determined by TARGETDIR\MYCOMPANYROOT.  I Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Have a read up on [TARGETDIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will see that this links to [ROOTDRIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which states:

> If ROOTDRIVE is not set at a command line or authored into the
>   Property table, the installer sets this property. During an
>   administrative installation the installer sets ROOTDRIVE to the first
>   connected network drive it finds that can be written to. If it is not
>   an administrative installation, or if the installer can find no
>   network drives, the installer sets ROOTDRIVE to the local drive that
>   can be written to having the most free space.

So I suspect that on the single machine which you are having issues with, that it has another local drive with more space than c:

Comment: David - This sounds promising, but I have been presented with a fire here at work that I will have to stamp out before I can get back to this.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: David - Ok, I looked at this and this wasn't the problem.  The machine in question only had one drive - the "C" drive.  I even made sure we were not installing from a network place.  I have a fix, that I don't understand.  I'll post that next.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
On one of our machines WIX installed on E drive (flash disk) instead of C dive.
I have come across this answer which solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591139/1891969

Just replace the TARGETDIR value with "C:\".

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="FormatTargetDirectory" After="CostFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Directory="TARGETDIR" Value="[DRIVE_NAMES]" Id="FormatTargetDirectory"/>
```